# Visual C# Appending a Text Box In Parallel For Loop - Cross Threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, textbox, parallel-processing

I am new to Visual C#, using Visual Studio. I have some calculations that are done in a parallel for loop, and I want to output something to the output text box inside this loop (keeps all output from the calculations on screen). I simply want to be able to append text to the text box (or add text to what is already there).

I found the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) on thread safe calls to windows forms. They show two examples both work for the case they present. They are simply displaying a message in the text box. I want to append data to the text box. I am able to get the following code (first way) to work:

```
    private void setTextSafeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.demoThread =
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));
        this.demoThread.Start();
    }


    private void ThreadProcSafe()
    {
        int length = 10;

        Parallel.For(1, length, j =>
        {
            //this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text + "Simulation Replication " + j.ToString() + "\r\n";
            this.SetText("Simulation Replication " + j.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }); // Parallel.For
     }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text + text;
        }
    }
```

This will produce the desired output:

Simulation Replication 4

Simulation Replication 2

Simulation Replication 7

...

However, if I try to use the first line inside (currently commented) the parallel for loop instead of the second line, I get the following error:

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

First question is, being new to parallel computing (done some in Matlab) and being new to Visual C#, what exactly is this error trying to tell me? Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Is it easier than the method that is working right now?

---

Now, I also have another issue. I attempted to use the other strategy suggested for this, which is using a background worker, with very similar code. If I just display a message and do not append, everything works fine. If I attempt to append, it does 5 parallel calculations and displays them and then the GUI gangs... just freezes, no error or anything, just stuck. The code I am using looks like this (the SetText is the same as in the code above):

```
    private void setTextBackgroundWorkerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int length = 10;

        Parallel.For(1, length, k =>
        {
            //this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text + "Simulation Replication " + k.ToString() + "\r\n";
            this.SetText("Simulation Replication " + k.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }); // Parallel.For

    }
```

It actually outputs the text for the first 5 and the indexes are 1,2,4,6,8. Is there something to the fact that these are strictly increasing?

I would like to understand why this code works in the above case, but seems to screw up using the background worker. I read that using background workers is the better way to go. Can someone show me a way to get the desired behavior using the background worker?

Finally, I actually just want to know what the best way to do this is. If I am executing a parallel for loop with many calculations (say it takes about 5 seconds to do all the calcs for one iteration), and I want to display the current index number when the iteration begins, what is the best way to do that within the parallel for loop? I want to keep all the data that was in the text box before getting to these parallel calculations...hence the need to append..

Any help or advice here would be much appreciated. It was easy to just tell it to write some output to the console in a console app, that is no problem (using both Matlab and C#). Using the text boxes seems to create an issue. Please Help!

Comment: Unfortunately, by default WinForms cross-thread calls have undefined behavior. To prevent it, add this line to the beginning of the program: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` Then run your test again.

Comment: In this new state, the program behaviour must be consistent: every illegal cross-thread call must fail immediately. The rule is: don't touch user interface from a worker thread.